# How to make Tab bar red using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am building chat app. The problem is that when the tab is lost focused, user can not know when the message arrive.

So, when message arrives, I want to make Tab bar Red & and when the browser got focus I want to clear the Red.

```
if(message){
     //make Tab bar red
}
```

**SO, how to do that in Javascript?**

Comment: May want to include some code

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: You mean the browser's tab? It's not possible. Have you ever seen a site that would do it?

Comment: Oh you meant browser tab? Yeah no that's not possible. Best you can do is implement web push notifications like the ones facebook uses.

Comment: Yes, The tab the current page

Comment: Not what you're looking for, but the best solution is [favico.js](http://lab.ejci.net/favico.js/)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can change in browser tab is the text:

```
if (message) {
    document.title = 'New Message!!!'
}
```